# Dense rank function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select node, parent, dense_rank() over (partition by parent order by node)
from tree
```

When I run this query I get

```
node parent (No column name)
1    0      1
2    1      1
3    1      2
4    2      1
5    2      2 
6    3      1 
7    3      2
```

Where I was expecting the following result

```
node    parent  (No column name)
1       0       1
2       1       2
3       1       2
4       2       3
5       2       3
6       3       4
7       3       4
```

Why does the dense rank function not group parent-wise?

Comment: Your expected result is not `dense_rank`. Your result is `parent + 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below script.

```
  select node,parent,dense_rank() over (order by parent) from tree
```

Sample Output :

[image]

Comment: if you use partition dense_rank () will count based on the partitioned column,means if there any change value of the partitioned column the count will reset to one.

Comment: Should be `over(order by parent, node)` yeah?

Answer (score 5):

**Try this:**

```
  select node,parent,dense_rank() over (order by parent) from tree
```

You don't have to use the partition in the `dense_rank()` just order by parent will do the job.

Comment: you have to use parent in the order by clause.

Comment: yup .. +1.. I also posted the same.. :)

Comment: sir i already get result but why partition is changing my result

Comment: @ARJUN When you partition it by parent it resets the RANK value for each parent. i.e for each parent value RANK will start from 1. So each new parent value you will have 1 and then if that parents have any more records RANK will be increased one by one.

Answer (score 3):

Use it without PARTITION:

```
;WITH tree AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1,0),(2, 1),(3, 1),(4, 2),(5, 2), (6, 3), (7, 3)
) as t(node, parent)
)

select  node,
        parent,
        dense_rank() over (order by parent) 
from tree
```

Output:

```
node    parent  (No column name)
1       0       1
3       1       2
2       1       2
5       2       3
4       2       3
7       3       4
6       3       4
```

Note: `PARTITION` divides the result set produced by the `FROM` clause into partitions to which the `DENSE_RANK` function is applied. So the result set is partitioned by `parent` and ordered by `node`. And you need *partition* over all the rows, that is why you don't need partition by any column.

Comment: what happen if i use partition

Answer (score 1):

You do not need partition by clause

```
declare @t table(node int, parent int)
insert into @t 
select 1,0 union all
select 2,1 union all
select 3,1 union all
select 4,2 union all
select 5,2 union all
select 6,3 union all
select 7,3 

select node,parent,dense_rank() over (order by parent)  from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want, based on expectations, is a (dense) ranking based on the parents of the nodes.

What you need to do to achieve this, is simply order by the parent. If you *partition* by parent, you're getting the rank of a node *within each parent*.

```sql
WITH
-- CTE to generate the same data
tree AS (
   SELECT 1 AS node, 0 AS parent
   UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 5, 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 6, 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 7, 3
)
SELECT
   node,
   parent,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY parent) AS your_rank
FROM tree;
```

Like the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) reads, partitioning...

> [d]ivides the result set produced by the FROM clause into partitions to which the DENSE_RANK function is applied.

So if you partition by parent, you're telling SQL Server to make little groups of nodes per parent and then calculate the rank *within that group*, starting over at 1 for each group.